# Process 'command '/home/ns1/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aidl'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-studio, build, build.gradle

i have import my old project i got this error Process 'command '/home/ns1/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aidl'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
how to solve this! i have try many solution like build clean,rebuild,Invalidate catch restart,check images name,check asset folder values,update build tool with 25.0.3 but still not solve error in my 3.4.1 android studio. i want this project with older version i don't want to upload into play store so please help me out.any suggestion or answer will be appreciate

Comment: I'm facing the similar issue... How did you solve this?